# Is there a way to send a CString to a CFile without writing an actual file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I have data stored in a `CString` and it needs to be parsed by an XML parser library. The problem is the XML parser takes in a `CFile`. It's not ideal to write out the `CString` to a text file and then reload it into a `CFile`. Is there any way to directly send the `CString` to the `CFile` without making an intermediate output file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use [CMemFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t8kd0z(VS.80).aspx) to accomplish this. It inherits from `CFile` and allows you to specify an arbitrary buffer for data. The following sample code should work:

```
CString strData;
CMemFile memFile( (BYTE*)strData.GetBuffer() , (strData.GetLength() + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR) );

//Do something with memFile

strData.ReleaseBuffer();
```

Comment: I tried your sample code, but the XML parser was unable to parse it due to a blank stream. Looking deeper into the XML parser it seems to be taking the `CFile` and putting it into a `CArchive`. I tried this: `CArchive archive( &memFile, CArchive::load );` to make it an archive and sent the archive as a parameter since the function has an overloaded constructor that takes in a `CArchive`. Does this make a difference?

Comment: I tried putting the `CMemFile` object inside a `CArchive` object and reading data from the archive, and it worked fine. The `strData` object in my sample code is just a blank string, are you replacing it with a string that contains the actual XML data?

Comment: Yes. I have `CString strData = blah.c_str();` with `blah` being the `<iostream>` string datatype containing the XML code.

Comment: That's strange. It's hard to tell what's going on without more information. Is the XML parser library freely available somewhere to look at?

Comment: I'm actually editing the open-source program TinyCad ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinycad/ ). The XML parser doesn't look like a library available anywhere else. I tried their support forum, but haven't had much luck.

Comment: Better late than never: I used `std::string` instead of CString. Instead of `CMemFile memFile( (BYTE*)strData.GetBuffer() , (strData.GetLength() + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR) );
` I used `CMemFile memFile( (BYTE*)strData.c_str(), strData.length() + 1);` with strData being a `std::string`. Hopefully this will help someone wandering around the internet.